# Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: {"size":0,"timeout":0} while using function web3.eth.getBalance()

Tags: heroku, web3js, hardhat

I'm new to web3 and i have been trying to deploy basic hardhat setup with default Lock.sol template code to heroku and run 'npx hardhat node' with start script.

I have a nodeJs app trying to connect to the hardhat server that is deployed to the above mentioned heroku-hardhat app.

following is my code :

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3("https://{myapp}.herokuapp.com");

async function getBalance(accountAddress) {
  console.log("Get Account balance called", accountAddress);
  console.log("web3", web3); // Web3 object is consoled properly here
  const balanceInWei = await web3.eth.getBalance(
    accountAddress,
    (err, balance) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error("Error while retrieving account balance :", err); // Here, i get the error mentioned in the title
        return 0;
      }
      console.log("Balance : ", web3.utils.fromWei(balance, "ether"), " ETH");
      return balance;
    }
  );
```

I can also see the accounts and private keys listed from the logs of heroku app once "npx hardhat node" is running

`Started HTTP and WebSocket JSON-RPC server at http://127.0.0.1:8545/`

But, the app shows the following

```
2022-12-11T19:11:27.462998+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-12-11T19:11:27.490453+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-12-11T19:11:27.639776+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2022-12-11T19:11:27.708051+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

and the node app is unable to retrieve response, it gets the following consoled :
`Error while retrieving account balance : Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: {"size":0,"timeout":0}`

But, when i initialise the web3 object with the following, it works properly :
`const web3 = new Web3("http://127.0.0.1:8545");`

I'm basically trying to send balance of hardhat fake wallet back to frontend through nodeJs app that is unable to get JSON response from the deployed heroku-hardhat app

Answer (score 0):

this error

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within
> 60 seconds of launch

indicates that your heroku app is not starting. this usually happens if you set your port like this:

```
const port = 3000;
const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}`));
```

in production, heroku assigns an environment variable for port. so you should set the port in your app like this

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

Since you were able to deploy the code heroku without issue, this might be the only issue in your app.